# Don't display facebook like button for those who already liked it

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I want to display a Facebook like button for a page only for those who didn't like that page. So, when a user is already a fan of the page , the like button will not be shown.

I did a lot of research and I found that I need to implement Facebook connect, and fetch the `user_likes` permission and check if the connected user has the page in his list. This is a working example http://www.fbrell.com/fb.api/does-like

Basicaly, I need the code that will do this :

When the user clicks on connect, the content will be changed and the Facebook like button will be shown if the connected user didn't like it in the past.

Comment: btw this demo does not work correctly ! It says that i liked the app, but I dont even have facebook

Comment: just a note:  when dealing with the like button, or like by api.  the plugin can no be modified and part of use is to provide a way for users to unlike if needed.  same as using api for likes, you are supposed to return a way for users to unlike.  or delete the like post.

Comment: @Mageek - See my edits.  Good job on editing the title - but there was a lot more work to be done on the post.  If you are already in there - fix it all :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Implement the [JavaScript SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/)

During the initialization of the JS SDK, make sure to set `xfbml` to false, so that the plugin will not be rendered automatically.  You'll have to [request the `user_likes` permission](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/) which means that you are going to have to associate your site with a Facebook application.  This is so that Facebook can keep track of who is requesting what data. You can use the [`Fb.login()`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/) method to request permissions and authenticate your users.

Once you have the JavaSctipt SDK you can simply make a call to the API via

- Graph
  `FB.api('me/likes/PAGE_ID')`
- FQL
  `FB.api("fql?q='SELECT+uid+FROM+page_fan+WHERE+uid=me()+AND+page_id=PAGE_ID")`

If those return data you know not to display the like plugin.  However, if the user has not liked the page yet, those calls will return empty results and then you can call the [`FB.XFBML.parse()`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.XFBML.parse/) method to render the like plugin.

Comment: No, sorry, I'm not in the business of doing other peoples work for them.  All the code you need is in the links I provided.  If you want to copy and paste you're better off taking it from the source.  Don't forget to substitute the APP_ID's for your own.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make some calls to the Graph API,
After you get the Page ID with `FB.api('http://your-url.com');`
you can check if current user like's your page with an FQL query:

```
'SELECT uid FROM page_fan WHERE uid=me() AND page_id=YOUR-PAGE-ID'
```

Answer (score 0):

If your like button is on a canvas page or a page tab you can implement a fan gate by reading the [signed_request](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/).
There is a ton of tutorials and hints on how to do it also here on stackoverflow for different server side languages. For example this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7671496/601466
Just search for "fan gate" and "signed request".

Comment: Only if the site is using the [Registration Plugin](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/registration/) will it be passed a [`signed_request`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/). I believe we are talking about an external website and not a page tab or canvas app.

Comment: well , i need it on a webpage