# I need a DIV to disappear IF the visitor is connected AND likes the fanpage

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I would like to add to Wordpress a DIV with a likebutton for the fanpage.

This like button and the text content in the div must disappear if the user that is surfing the blog likes the fanpage.

Can you please give me the instructions to achieve this?

For example, how to make disappear this code?

```
<div id="disappear-if-likes">
text <br>
facebook like button code
</div>
```

P.s. I am not a PHP expert, so please consider it :)

Answer (score 0):

To make your disappearing div, you've got to know who your user is and be able to read what they've liked. In order to get this information, you need to have a user log in via a Facebook app you've created, then query their user record. This is not something you're going to get quickly, and you're not going to be able to do without either some intermediate level PHP or javascript.

The best bet is to use the [Facebook login button](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like). This lives on your site in a Facebook-hosted iframe, so Facebook can interact with a user they know (but you don't). Their buttons change status based on the user's like status.

To make this button "like" your fan page, just add your fan page's url (https://facebook.com/PAGE_USERNAME_OR_ID) instead of your site's url in the arguments.

Comment: Yeah, thanks. I am using that already.I wanted to put an image in the bottom of the posts and somewhere aside that appears only if they don't like the fanpage.

If I put this button also in the bottom of each post, somebody can click it by mistake thinking they are liking the post, but the button is already clicked and they may un-fan the fanpage.I'd like to avoid it.

I found this, but not sure if this is what I need: http://www.parorrey.com/blog/facebook-apps-development/how-to-check-facebook-page-liked-by-user-like-gate-facebook-iframe-tab-using-php-graph-api/comment-page-1/#comment-2387

Answer (score 0):

Facebook has added event callbacks.

```
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create',
    function(response) {
        alert('You liked the URL: ' + response);
    }
);
```

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/

I think this will help.

Comment: Thanks, I understand I have to put it inside `<script></script>`. Where should I put the code I want to hide to fans?

Comment: I mean, if the users can see the code, no problem. I just want to hide a DIV with the text inside, etc. It can be visible in the source, but I just want to make the div disappear in the browser view if they are fans.

If they are not fans or not connected I want to show them a message that encourages them to become fans.

Comment: may be this will help you -  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11285552/dont-display-facebook-like-button-for-those-who-already-liked-it

Comment: This will only fire once, when they actually like the page, so I don't think it is what you need. ps. I meant the original answer, the comment link looks promising.

Answer (score 0):

You found this link yourself, Pikk, but didn't seem sure if it was what you wanted.  I figured I would post here to clarify.

http://www.parorrey.com/blog/facebook-apps-development/how-to-check-facebook-page-liked-by-user-like-gate-facebook-iframe-tab-using-php-graph-api

That is what you need.  The issue is that unless you have integrated the facebook API with your site, and users are connecting and authenticating with it, you can't really tell whether they have liked you or not when they visit your website.

Now pages / apps hosted directly on facebook CAN tell this information.  So what you want to do is create a facebook app, using the code referenced in the link, except have it either display an image, or display nothing.  Then on your wordpress site you will create an iframe at the bottom of each post, and load that facebook app's URL.

As you mentioned you are not a PHP expert, it may be a little outside of your comfort zone, but that should accomplish what you want.

Comment: Hi, I have already some app, maybe that's the one we need. Let me explain. I have iframe and FBML like button in the site. In addition, under every post I am using the FB comments social plugin. In order to moderate the comments and in order to use the iframe I had to create an app. The APP is linked to my blog and to my fanpage. Everything is working fine.

When you say that I need an APP, would that APP be good to achieve what I need, or you mean that I need such kind of app, where users MUST click on "accept" somewhere in some popup window?

Comment: I think I am ready to go. I found this article: http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/facebook-open-graph-wordpress/

All of that is running on my blog months already. Part of that was added manually, the other part thanks to the "Like-Button-Plugin-For-Wordpress" plugin. The fb:admins, fb:app_id, and many other og stuff are there. Am I ready to go ahead? Do you have a simple code I can try somewhere? Eg. in the footer just for testing?